# Is libwebp 0.3.0-3 used by pillow on Centos 7 concerned by CVE-2020-36328?

Tags: security, python-imaging-library, centos7, nessus, rapid7

We scanned the same host (a `CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)`) with two vulnerability scanners (Nessus and Rapid7).

- Rapid7 reported that `libwebp-0:0.3.0-7.el7.x86_64` is vulnerable [CVE-2020-36328](https://www.rapid7.com/db/vulnerabilities/centos_linux-cve-2020-36328/).
- Nessus did not report a vulnerability, the plugin [CentOS 7 : qt5-qtimageformats (CESA-2021:2328)](https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/150762) did not fire.

The installed library (`libwebp-0:0.3.0-7.el7.x86_64`) is used by `python-pillow-0:2.0.0-19.gitd1c6db8.el7.x86_64` and not by `qt5-qtimageformats` (against which the test is done)

**My question**: which one these two scanners is reporting correct information?

Or in other words: is this vulnerability strictly linked to the package that uses it, or is a standalone library vulnerable as well?